# Capital Letters in Mongoid Model (Rails) getting errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, mongoid

I created a model in mongoid ATSJob, but whenever I call it anywhere, it gives me a:

`uninitialized constant name_of_current_file::ATSJob`

I assume that there's something off about having multiple capitals in a model name, but I don't know how to fix it to be what I want.

To further clarify, when I change the name back to Atsjob in the model, it works.

Thanks!

Comment: I don't think this is a problem with the model name. It appears that your model is not in the load path, hence "uninitialized constant". Did you place this model in the app/models directory? +1

Comment: Yeah, sorry let me clarify

Comment: what is the actual file name? Rails has a convention that the filename must match the constant name.

Comment: the name is atsjob.rb

Comment: does the answer below work for you?

Answer (score 0):

Rails has a convention that the model must be singular form of the table name and that the file name must match the constant name. If you have a table called atsjobs, then your model name is `Atsjob`, which should live in a file called `atsjob.rb`. Now if you want to make it camelcase, then you would create a model called `AtsJob`, which will live in a file called `ats_job.rb` (notice the underscore). The file name has a convention with the model name. Hence, there should be an underscore per capital letter.

Thus, in your case, try the following for the file name:

```
a_t_s_job.rb
```

That said, I would use camelcase over this approach. Something like AtsJob.rb is more conventional.

Comment: how do I make it ATSJob though?

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the name ATSJob instead of AtsJob, you can add "ATS" as an acronym in the ActiveSupport Inflector.  There should already be an initializer named "inflections.rb" in the config/initializers folder.  Modify or create this file with something along the lines of:

```
ActiveSupport::Inflector.inflections(:en) do |inflect|
  inflect.acronym 'ATS'
end
```

More information on the Inflector here:
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/Inflector.html